# What does get() method do on a CollectionReference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

When we look at the NodeJS API for working with Firesore CollectionReference objects, we find that it has a method called `get()`.  This is documented here:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get

And states:

> Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.

The sample code on the page is shown as:

```
let query = firestore.collection('col').where('foo', '==', 'bar');

query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
    console.log(`Found document at ${documentSnapshot.ref.path}`);
  });
});
```

However, this has me confused.  In the example code, the `get()` method is being executed on an object of type `Query` and not on a `CollectionReference` and hence doesn't seem to apply.  I'm missing what *query* the `get()` method on `CollectionReference` might be executing against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [API documentation for CollectionReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html) (scroll down just a bit), a CollectionReference **is a Query**, since it inherits from Query.  There is a second called "extends" and you see Query there.  This Query will return all of the documents in the collection.  When you call `where()` on that CollectionReference Query, it returns a new Query with the filter applied.